Python Pandas Transpose
I want to transpose the dataset below based on the Doc. # column which is a key number for each respective field name and reformat to be horizontal with respective New/Old value columns.The original data
I have tried both df.transpose() to reformat the dataframe and df.groupby() methods and can't get the ideal output below.Desired output

Please don't use images of data, provide a [mre]

This can be accomplished via a melt and a pivot. The trick here is that since
you have repeated values in the "field" column, you will need to build a
dependent "helper" column for the pivot operation to place the values where
you expect them to be. After the transformation, this helper can be removed.
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'field': ['key', 'abc', 'abc', 'def', 'def'],
    'doc': ['167851'] * 5,
    'new_value': ['jones', 'emm', pd.NA, 'kia', 'honda'],
    'old_value': ['rob', 'met', 'pending', 'hyundai', 'toyota'],
})

print(
    df.melt(id_vars=['field', 'doc'])
    .assign(_field_helper=lambda d: d.groupby(['field', 'variable']).cumcount())
    .pivot(index=['doc', 'variable'], columns=['field', '_field_helper'], values='value')
    .droplevel(level=1, axis=1) # removes the helper column index level
    .reset_index()              # clean up output to closely mimic OP desired output
    .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
)
#       doc   variable    key  abc      abc      def     def
# 0  167851  new_value  jones  emm     <NA>      kia   honda
# 1  167851  old_value    rob  met  pending  hyundai  toyota


For a deeper example, where you have multiple entities in 'doc', you’ll
need to also group on 'doc' when calculating the helper column.
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

buffer = StringIO('''
field     doc new_value old_value
  key  167851     jones       rob
  abc  167851       emm       met
  abc  167851      <NA>   pending
  def  167851       kia   hyundai
  def  167851     honda    toyota
  key  167852     porti      jake
  abc  167852      audi      ford
  abc  167852     lexus     chevy
  def  167852       met        up
''')

df = pd.read_table(buffer, sep='\s+')


print(
    df.melt(id_vars=['field', 'doc'])
    .assign(_field_helper=lambda d: d.groupby(['doc', 'field', 'variable']).cumcount())
    .pivot(index=['doc', 'variable'], columns=['field', '_field_helper'], values='value')
    .droplevel(level=1, axis=1) # removes the helper column index level
    .reset_index()              # clean up output to closely mimic OP desired output
    .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
)
#       doc   variable    key   abc      abc      def     def
# 0  167851  new_value  jones   emm      NaN      kia   honda
# 1  167851  old_value    rob   met  pending  hyundai  toyota
# 2  167852  new_value  porti  audi    lexus      met     NaN
# 3  167852  old_value   jake  ford    chevy       up     NaN


If there was multiple doc # how would you change it?

just added another example for this case.
